# Displaying specific content to specific user in Joomla 1.5

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, acl

To be short, It's a website for an investigations lab.
I need to display specific content (lab report) to specific user. Users will be given a username and a password when leaving and will be asked to login on the website to access his/her report with the credentials given to him.

**So , it's a "specific content" for "specific user" - Moving to 1.6 is not an option.**

I have a solution in mind but involve a lot of core hacking and will take some time ... If any one been in a similar situation or have an idea in mind I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this can be done but it's going to take a little trickery to get there. First, you are going to need a way to post the lab reports and associate them with a user. I would use K2 for this since you can add the report as an attachment to an item. You can also add extra fields to K2, which would be the next step. You'll need an extra field where you can enter a user ID number that you will use to determine if a user is allowed to view the content.

There are several steps you will need to take to now filter the content so only the associated user can see it.

1. You will need to get the user ID once the user is logged in:

   $user =& JFactory::getUser();

   $usr_id = $user->get('id');
2. You'll need a menu item that links to a K2 Category where all the lab reports go.
3. You'll need a subtemplate with a modified category_item.php for that category that only displays the associate reports:

   if($this->item->extra_fields[USER_ID_EXTRA_FIELD_NAME]==$usr_id){

   all the category item stuff

   }
4. You'll need a subtemplate with a modified item.php for the category that again blocks users other than the associated user, basically the same code as #3 to either display the content or an error message.

The only other way I can think of that you can accomplish this would be to use an ACL component with a group for each user.

The K2 method with subtemplates would not require any core hacks and will work with a little work.

Comment: This is quite an impressive use of K2 + template overrides - I like your thinking. Thanks for sharing Brent!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want with Flexicontent http://www.flexicontent.org/ and Flexiaccess

Flexicontent is a K2 type component and I use them interchangeably. With Flexiaccess you can create items that are only available to certain users.

No hacks required.

Comment: Wouldn't this have the same issue as other ACLs? You'd need a group for each user right?

Comment: Yes, although I do believe you can assign user by user permissions. It's just not a 'hack'.

Answer (score 0):

Bad News: That cant be done with standard Joomla 1.5 (without hacking)
Good News: You can use one of the free or commercial Extensions for Joomla to accomplish that. I would suggest for example:

Admin-User-Access
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/backend-a-full-access-control/9040

Or you can search for yourself:
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/backend-a-full-access-control

Comment: I've checked every addon on JED ... This cannot be done using the suggested extension cause it will involve creating a user group for every user. Thanks for suggestion though ...